# Cassandra2.1 write slow in a 1TB data table

Tags: cassandra, nosql

I am doing some test in a cassandra cluster,and now i have a table with 1TB data per node.When i used ycsb to do more insert operation,i found the throughput was really low(about 10000 ops/sec) comparing to a same,new table in the same cluster(about 80000 ops/sec).While inserting,the cpu usage was about 40%,and almost no disk usege.

I used nodetool tpstats to get task details,it showed :

```
Pool Name                    Active   Pending      Completed   Blocked  All time blocked
CounterMutationStage              0         0              0         0                 0
ReadStage                         0         0            102         0                 0
RequestResponseStage              0         0       41571733         0                 0
MutationStage                   384     21949       82375487         0                 0
ReadRepairStage                   0         0              0         0                 0
GossipStage                       0         0         247100         0                 0
CacheCleanupExecutor              0         0              0         0                 0
AntiEntropyStage                  0         0              0         0                 0
MigrationStage                    0         0              6         0                 0
Sampler                           0         0              0         0                 0
ValidationExecutor                0         0              0         0                 0
CommitLogArchiver                 0         0              0         0                 0
MiscStage                         0         0              0         0                 0
MemtableFlushWriter              16        16           4745         0                 0
MemtableReclaimMemory             0         0           4745         0                 0
PendingRangeCalculator            0         0              4         0                 0
MemtablePostFlush                 1       163           9394         0                 0
CompactionExecutor                8        29          13713         0                 0
InternalResponseStage             0         0              0         0                 0
HintedHandoff                     2         2              5         0                 0
```

I found there was a large amount of pending MutationStage and MemtablePostFlush

I have read some related articles about cassandra write limitation,but no useful information.I want to know why there is a huge difference about cassandra throughput between two same tables except the data size?

---

In addition,i use **ssd** on my server.However,this phenomenon also occur in another cluster using hdd

---

When cassandra was running,i found the both %user and  %nice on cpu utilization are about 10% while only compactiontask running with compaction throughput about 80MB/S.but i have been set nice value to 0 for my cassandra process.

Comment: You should try to increase the compaction throughput with nodetool setcompactionthroughput

Comment: i have tried,but it not work.

Answer (score 0):

Wild guess: your system is busy compacting the sstable.
Check it out with `nodetool compactionstats`

BTW, YCSB does not use prepare statement, which make it bad estimator for actual application load.